# images as sequence in image texture node doesn't work

Tags: animation, texture-baking

I created 3 different oceans with ocean modifier with different displacement and used linear extrapolation to animate it.
I then baked the 3 simulations.
After that i created a new plane and applied the baked ocean sims as texture to animate it and apply the displacement. the problem is only one frame out of the 150 is being applied instead of the entire animation even though i use image as sequence option in image texture. Also in the blend file if u unhide the displacement collection you can see the different oceans.

Comment: Please add your blend file to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have auto update enabled in the image sequence node. If it's disabled it won't update the frame in the viewport when you play or scrub the timeline. But even it's disabled it should play correctly when rendering.
If you want the texture to loop, also enable "cyclic" or the texture will pause on the last frame. And for good measure check if the 'Frames' number is correct (this number should be the number of frames in your image sequence).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem that only the first image was loaded.
In my case the file names were not congruent (image_01, picture_02, photo_03, ...) Changing them to image_01, image_02, image_03, ... has fixed this problem